# Nodejs Clustering Socket.io - Only Worker 2 is used when there are active workers

Tags: node.js, multithreading, socket.io

I am trying to implement clustering and sticky sessions with Node.js from [this example](https://github.com/elad/node-cluster-socket.io).
However, whenever a client connects to `localhost:3000`, no matter how many clients are already connected, they will all connect to Worker 2.

Here's the code that I use.

```
var express = require('express'),
        cluster = require('cluster'),
        net = require('net'),
        sio = require('socket.io'),
        sio_redis = require('socket.io-redis');

var port = 3000,
    num_processes = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // This stores our workers. We need to keep them to be able to reference
    // them based on source IP address. It's also useful for auto-restart,
    // for example.
    var workers = [];

    // Helper function for spawning worker at index 'i'.
    var spawn = function(i) {
        workers[i] = cluster.fork();

        // Optional: Restart worker on exit
        workers[i].on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
            console.log('respawning worker', i);
            spawn(i);
        });
    };

    // Spawn workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        spawn(i);
    }

    // Helper function for getting a worker index based on IP address.
    // This is a hot path so it should be really fast. The way it works
    // is by converting the IP address to a number by removing the dots,
    // then compressing it to the number of slots we have.
    //
    // Compared against "real" hashing (from the sticky-session code) and
    // "real" IP number conversion, this function is on par in terms of
    // worker index distribution only much faster.
    var workerIndex = function (ip, len) {
    var _ip = ip.split(/['.'|':']/),
        arr = [];

    for (el in _ip) {
        if (_ip[el] == '') {
            arr.push(0);
        }
        else {
            arr.push(parseInt(_ip[el], 16));
        }
    }

    return Number(arr.join('')) % len;
}

    // Create the outside facing server listening on our port.
    var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function(connection) {
        // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
        // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
        // it the connection.
        var worker = workers[workerIndex(connection.remoteAddress, num_processes)];
        worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
    }).listen(port);
} else {
    // Note we don't use a port here because the master listens on it for us.
    var app = new express();

    // Here you might use middleware, attach routes, etc.

    // Don't expose our internal server to the outside.
    app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));//set the root directory for web visitors
    var server = app.listen(0, 'localhost'),
        io = sio(server);

    // Tell Socket.IO to use the redis adapter. By default, the redis
    // server is assumed to be on localhost:6379. You don't have to
    // specify them explicitly unless you want to change them.
    io.adapter(sio_redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

    console.log('starting worker: '+ cluster.worker.id);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('connected to worker: ' + cluster.worker.id);
    });

    // Here you might use Socket.IO middleware for authorization etc.

    // Listen to messages sent from the master. Ignore everything else.
    process.on('message', function(message, connection) {
        if (message !== 'sticky-session:connection') {
            return;
        }

        // Emulate a connection event on the server by emitting the
        // event with the connection the master sent us.
        server.emit('connection', connection);

        connection.resume();
    });
}
```

When I run it, I see

```
starting worker: 1
starting worker: 2
starting worker: 3
starting worker: 4
```

But whenever I connect to `localhost:3000` through socket.io, be it from a html page or by using another server as client

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

All I see is

```
connected to worker: 2
```

Even when I connect from multiple windows and different browsers, at the same time.

I put an interval in the worker block to see if the other worker were still alive after they are created.

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("I, worker " + cluster.worker.id + ", am alive");
}, 1000);
```

All of them are answering to that every second. So I thought that maybe the CPU simply never needs to send connecting clients to another worker. So I added an actual application to each worker, with visual feedback through the browser (a game basically). I used artillery to send more and more players to the game and I could experience lags and at some point it just wouldn't be smooth anymore, still, the terminal shows that all connecting clients are only going to `Worker 2`. (Note that if I manually set `num_processes` to 1, connections go to worker 1 as they should, but as soon as I make it 2 or more, all connections always go to worker 2).

Is there anything I need to do make all the other workers be used equally? Or is there anything I've got wrong?

Comment: Are you running on Windows?  If so, you can force the scheduler to use the round robin policy (which is not the default for Windows) with `cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_RR;`.  Details here: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel bad for not thinking of this before, but the answer is simpler than I had thought: the algorithm above uses the connecting IP address to determine what worker to assign it to. Using different browsers didn't change anything because I was still connecting from the same computer.

By the way I'm talking about this function in the master

```
var workerIndex = function (ip, len) {
    var _ip = ip.split(/['.'|':']/),
        arr = [];

    for (el in _ip) {
        if (_ip[el] == '') {
            arr.push(0);
        }
        else {
            arr.push(parseInt(_ip[el], 16));
        }
    }

    return Number(arr.join('')) % len;
}
```

Since the master is listening on the port for connections, instead of the workers, it is also the one to decide which worker handles which connection in here:

```
var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function(connection) {
    // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
    // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
    // it the connection.
    var worker = workers[workerIndex(connection.remoteAddress, num_processes)];
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
}).listen(port);
```

It works well when I put it online and connect from different devices.
The only concern I have with that is that if at some point all the connecting IP addresses boil down to be multiples of 4 (or anything else) after formatting, one worker would have a heavier load. But that's an edge case that probably hardly happens.

Anyways, I know other people posted similar issues and didn't get answered. I hope this can guide someone the right way.

Thanks a bunch [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) for your help!